# C++ / SDL animation speed

Tags: c++, animation, sdl, frame-rate

so I am working on a game, following a tutorial online. Currently I have some FPS built into the system, and a simple animation which uses pieces of a sprite like such:

```
if( frameCount > 12 )
        frameCount = 0;

    //hero frames   
    SDL_Rect clip[ 13 ];

    clip[ 0 ].x = 0;
    clip[ 0 ].y = 0;
    clip[ 0 ].w = 44;
    clip[ 0 ].h = 39;

    clip[ 1 ].x = 51;
    clip[ 1 ].y = 0;
    clip[ 1 ].w = 44;
    clip[ 1 ].h = 39;

    clip[ 2 ].x = 102;
    clip[ 2 ].y = 0;
    clip[ 2 ].w = 44;
    clip[ 2 ].h = 39;
    ...
    ...
    SDL_BlitSurface( hero, &clip[ frameCount ], destination, &offset );
    frameCount++;
```

Now this works just fine, and each iteration of the while loop will cause it to play the next frame in the animation (This animation is part of a character class by the way).

The problem I am facing is the speed of the animation. It takes place at the current FPS of the game, which is 60. I want to be able to control the speed of the player animation separately, so I can slow it down to a reasonable speed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about doing this?

note: There are 13 frames all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have separate your refresh rate (60 fps) from your animation rate. The best solution, in my opinion, is to tie your animation rate to the real time clock. In SDL, you can do this with the SDL_Ticks() function, which you can use to measure time in millisecond resolution.

As an example, consider this example (not working code, just a sketch):

```
void init() {
    animationRate = 12;
    animationLength = 13;
    startTime = SDL_Ticks();
}

void drawSprite() {
    int frameToDraw = ((SDL_Ticks() - startTime) * animationRate / 1000) % animationLength;
    SDL_BlitSurface( hero, &clip[ frameToDraw ], destination, &offset );
}
```

In case it isn't clear, the `frameToDraw` variable is computed by calculating how much time passed since the animation started to play. You multiply that by the animation rate and you get how many absolute frames at the animation rate have passed. You then apply the modulo operator to reduce this number to the range of your animation length and that gives you the frame you need to draw at that time.

If your refresh rate is slower than your animation rate your sprite will skip frames to keep up with the requested animation rate. If the refresh rate is faster then the same frame will be drawn repeatedly until the time to display the next frame comes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Its actually called [SDL_GetTicks()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) and not `SDL_Ticks()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

What Miguel has written works great. Another method you can use is, to use a timer, set it to fire at a certain frequency and in that frequency, increment your sprite index.

Note that you should **always** make your rendering and logic separate.

Comment: I agree, this solution would work too, but it will use more CPU if your display rate falls below the animation rate, as you will still be updating your animation state at full speed.

Comment: I agree that your method is faster. This method however is a bit more general. For example if you want to skip a sprite change during a period or do other stuff, your formula gets complicated.

Comment: The way I address sprite changes in my solution is by having each character keep track of its state. The game logic triggers state changes, and a change in state means that the animation can stop, or change to a different set of frames, etc. Each sprite knows what its possible states are. It's really easy, actually.